# Calculate budget per week and how many weeks there are left

Tags: php, date, datetime-format

I want to calculate how many weeks there are left from a specific date to another date, in order to get the budget per week. Here's my code:

```
$date_from = new DateTime('2015-07-28');
$date_to = new DateTime();
$interval = $date_from->diff($date_to);
$daysleft = ($interval->format('%a') + 1);
$weeksleft = number_format($daysleft / 7);

echo ('3164.49' / $weeksleft);
```

That code prints `3 167,76` for the last 2 weeks which of course is wrong. But what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you checked what the `$weeksleft` variable contains? How about the `$daysleft` Could it be because your `3164.49` is a string and not a number?

Comment: for me the code outputs `1582.245` thats on php version 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date_from = new DateTime('2015-07-28');
$date_to = new DateTime();
$interval = $date_from->diff($date_to);
$daysleft = ($interval->format('%a') + 1);
$weeksleft = number_format($daysleft / 7);

echo (floatval('3164.49') / $weeksleft);
```

Results
1582.245

Comment: This was more helpful since it's using the same code I'm using. I forgot to add a variable to the echo line. It's now showing the right sum. Thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome, I am happy to be able to give back to such a great community of programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different way as shown below.

```
$a = strtotime('2015/07/28');
$b = time();
$diff = abs($a - $b);
echo round($diff/(60*60*24*7)); // to get round figure
```

Answer (score 0):

I get 1582.245 .. Check/set your timezone settings.

```
date_default_timezone_set ($timezone_identifier)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

try this function,

```
function datediffInWeeks($date1, $date2)
{
if($date1 > $date2) return datediffInWeeks($date2, $date1);
$first = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date1);
$second = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date2);
return floor($first->diff($second)->days/7);
}

var_dump(datediffInWeeks('1/2/2013', '6/4/2013'));// 21
```